# How to add a Symfony2 translation containing a link inside of Doctrine @UniqueEntity Constraint?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I am trying to add a link inside the @UniqueEntity message inside my Doctrine mapping so that the link is not hardcoded inside the translation file. I am invoking this with Symfony2 forms.

Doctrine mapping:

```
@UniqueEntity(
  fields={"email"},
  message="form.error.email_exists"
)
```

Translation file:

```
 <trans-unit id="a81086a8eea38842e4c8351657840086" resname="form.error.email_exists">
    <source>form.error.email_exists</source>
    <target>We have an account with that email. %link1%Forgot your login?%linkEnd%</target>
 </trans-unit>
```

Normally you would just pass the %link1% through a translation filter, but I don't know how to do this within an annotation or if it is even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the only way to accomplish this was to hardcode the link into the translation file using CDATA.

```
 <trans-unit id="a81086a8eea38842e4c8351657840086" resname="form.error.email_exists">
    <source>form.error.email_exists</source>
    <target>We have an account with that email. <![CDATA[<a href="www.example.com/forgotLogin">Forgot your login?</a>]]></target>
  </trans-unit>
```

The problem with this solution is that there is no way to specify a specific domain within the translation file, But it at least works.

Answer (score 0):

Constraint messages can be translated. To do so you need a translation file that is called **validators.en.xml** where **en** stands for the language. See [this chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages)